# parameter in function of ng-click not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<a href ng-click='navigateTo("/blog/1000")'>
    {{ blog.blogId}} 
</a>

<a href ng-click='navigateTo("/blog/{{ blog.blogId}}")'>
    {{ blog.blogId}}
</a>
```

navigateTo is a function to change $location.path() and save some data.

Both hrefs have the same html output, yet only the top one works. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use interpolation inside `ngClick`:

```
<a href ng-click='navigateTo("/blog/"+blog.blogId)'>
```